# Vite - `declare const` to prevent typescript from flagging defines doesn't actually work

Tags: typescript, vite

[The Vite documentation for `define`](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#define) advises to "add the type declarations in the `env.d.ts` or `vite-env.d.ts` file to get type checks and Intellisense."

The value gets replaced correctly, but *TypeScript still complains.*

**vite.config.js**

```
const web_describe = execSync("git describe --dirty").toString().trim();
const meta_describe = execSync("git -C ./path/to/submodule describe --dirty").toString().trim();

export default defineConfig({
    // ...
    define: {
        __WEB_GIT_DESCRIBE__: JSON.stringify(web_describe),
        __META_GIT_DESCRIBE__: JSON.stringify(meta_describe),
    },
});
```

(i think someone edited this out of the question for some reason?)
**vite-env.d.ts**

```
// actual values in vite.config.js
// this is just to trick TypeScript into not flagging them in App.vue
declare const __WEB_GIT_DESCRIBE__: string;
declare const __META_GIT_DESCRIBE__: string;
```

**App.vue** (snippet)
[image]

[tsconfig.json](https://pastebin.com/uFHw9HH1) - Template from tsc, the only thing I changed is `strictNullChecks`. ~~Adding it didn't change anything.~~

---

### Edit 2023-03-21

The error spontaneously fixed itself when i added tsconfig except apparently i didn't notice. shoutout to `git bisect`.

```
commit 09b4c32d098922d62ea57cdb3dadd24a63d9b895 (HEAD)
Author: Connor King <sigstackfault@gmail.com>
Date:   Sun Mar 19 13:23:58 2023 -0400

    ts-ify Ship.ts

 src/Component.ts         |  16 +++++++++-------
 src/{Ship.js => Ship.ts} | 139 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++--------------------------------------------------
 tsconfig.json            | 103 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 3 files changed, 201 insertions(+), 57 deletions(-)
```

if you can figure out *what* in my tsconfig fixed it (for the sake of people in the future with this same problem but who already have a tsconfig), i'll accept the answer.

edit 2023-03-22: [link to my whole damn project](https://gitlab.com/SIGSTACKFAULT/fleetwright-web-designer). it's for a wargame/ttrpg we're making.

Comment: did this help? [How to properly use vitejs define?](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/3058)

Comment: doesn't say anything about typescript.

also i forgot to write this in the question but it works fine. it's just the red underline.

Comment: Is the `vite-env.d.ts` file definitely being used by TypeScript? Please share your TS config.

Comment: I didn't have tsconfig when i wrote this question and adding one didn't change anything.

Comment: Please include the contents of the `vite-env.d.ts` file again. Not sure if it was intentionally edited out.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes wasn't me, i'll add it again

Comment: @SIGSTACKFAULT can you please check if creating an EMPTY (just `{}`) tsconfig fixes the error?

Comment: @Dimava it does! very interesting. I added a link to my whole project if you want to look.

Answer (score 2):

You MUST have a `tsconfig.json` file for globals to work AT ALL <sup>even an emply `{}` one is enough</sup>

Othervise your files are considered standalone scripts that have so scope other then things they explicitly `import` or reference with "triple-slash reference"  `/// <reference path="./vite-env.d.ts" />`

Answer (score 1):

try writing

```
// some .d.ts, vite-env.d.ts is fine
declare global {
  const __WEB_GIT_DESCRIBE__: string;
}
```

Your `vite-env.d.ts` can fail to make consts global because:

- it is considered a module and not a global d.ts because it has `import` or `export` or whatever

Comment: didn't change anything. my entire vite-env.d.ts is just the two `declare const` lines and some comments.

Comment: This does not work even with a non-empty `tsconfig.json`.